# How to follow a PL/SQL block with DDL Statements

Tags: oracle, plsql

How can I follow a PL/SQL block with DDL Statements?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
DECLARE TRESULT INTEGER;

BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(1) INTO TRESULT
    FROM USER_INDEXES
    WHERE INDEX_NAME='IX_SalesmanID';

  IF TRESULT > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX IX_SalesmanID';
  END IF;

END;

CREATE INDEX IX_SalesmanID ON Salesmen(SalesmanID);
```

But I get an error message:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 15, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" 
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

I should be outside the block, though, right?

This is a very simplified version, the actual script would check for the existence of a number of things, and drop, recreate and repeatedly alter many objects and many of their attributes. Putting all of them in dynamic SQL strings and using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE seems like overkill.

Am I doing something simple wrong in trying to close the block in the example above?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: put a '/' (slash sign) after "END;"

Comment: just as something to think about, unless you are doing a migration,repeatedly dropping and recreating objects in Oracle is not a good practice for a production box and can indicate that the problem you are trying to solve has not been completely thought out.

Comment: Any time you find yourself trying to do DDL in a pl/sql block, you should push back from the keyboard, go get a cup of coffee, and rethink what you are doing.  I'll never say never, but it is a huge red flag that you are taking the wrong approach.  And this is certainly one of those cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `;` terminates a PL/SQL statement and a `/` terminates a PL/SQL block in the SQL scope:

```
DECLARE
  TRESULT INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  INTO   TRESULT
  FROM   USER_INDEXES
  WHERE  INDEX_NAME='IX_SALESMANID'; -- All UPPERCASE

  IF TRESULT > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX IX_SalesmanID';
  END IF;
END;
/

CREATE INDEX IX_SalesmanID ON Salesmen(SalesmanID);
```

Comment: Oh, yes; Thank you. Been some years since I used Oracle instead of SQL Server or other database.